# How to transform array of strings into specific tree structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapping

I get a list of file paths from the backend, it represents a folder structure and looks like this:

```
paths = ["path/to/file1.doc", "path/to/file2.doc", "foo/bar.doc]
```

The lengths of the paths are arbitrary. In order to use a file tree component ([angular2-tree-component](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component)) I need to transform this data into the [following format](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/options-1):

```
nodes = [
    {
        "name": "path",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "to",
                "children": [
                    {"name": "file1.doc"},
                    {"name": "file2.doc"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "children": [
            {"name": "bar.doc"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I *think* the most efficient way to transform the data is to

1. Map the array with the files mirroring a tree structure first and then to
2. Iterate over every key in order to finalise the "children/parent" relations.

Step one:

```
transformToTree(data) {
    const tree = {};
    function addPathsToTree(paths) {
        let map = tree
        paths.forEach(function(item) {
            map[item] = map[item] || {};
            map = map[item];
        });
    }
    data.forEach(function(path) {
        let pathPart = path.split('/');
        addPathsToTree(pathPart);
    });
    return pathTree;
}
```

When passing "nodes" into the transformToTree function (transformToTree(nodes)), I get the following result:

```
{
    "path": {
        "to": {
            "file1.doc": {},
            "file2.doc": {}
        }
    },
    "foo": {
        "bar": {}
    }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed from here = how to iterate over all the keys and values while building the final array in the required structure.

There are a few examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062922/how-to-get-all-keys-with-values-from-nested-objects/47063174) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085004/iterate-through-nested-javascript-objects) on SO, but I was not able to understand how I could adapt them to my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with two nested loops, one for pathes and one for the splitted names and find the name or create new objects.

```js
var paths = ["path/to/file1.doc", "path/to/file2.doc", "foo/bar.doc"],
    result = [];
    
paths.reduce((r, path) => {
    path.split('/').reduce((o, name) => {
        var temp = (o.children = o.children || []).find(q => q.name === name);
        if (!temp) o.children.push(temp = { name });
        return temp;
    }, r);
    return r;
}, { children: result });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Smart. Thank you very much for your help!